# Does async/await blocks event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I was reading [Don't Block the Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/) from the Node.js guide. There was a line saying:

> You should make sure you never block the Event Loop. In other words,
>   each of your JavaScript callbacks should complete quickly. This of
>   course also applies to your `await`'s, your `Promise.then`'s, and so on.

I started to wonder, what if, some API call to the database which I'm `await`ing is taking some time to resolve, does that mean that I have blocked the event loop with that `await` call?

After that, I started testing some self written codes but after testing  I'm still not clear how blocking through `await` works. Here are some testing codes:

Assuming, that I'm using express for testing. I understand why making 2 API calls to the `/test` route blocks the event loop in this case.

```
function someHeavyWork() {
  // like calling pbkdf2 function
}

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  someHeavyWork();
  res.json(data);
});
```

But that doesn't happen in this case.

```
function fakeDBCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(data);
    }, 5000)
  })
}

app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await fakeDbCall();
  res.json(data);
})
```

This may be because of my lack of understanding of how blocking works in the case of `async/await`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Contrary to what it seems, `await` does not block. It's just ***syntactic sugar*** over promises. Nothing is blocked; it may look blocking to allow code to be synchronous, but that's just sugar over promises. For example, this may look synchronous:

```
const response = await fetch(…);
const json = await response.json();
const foo = JSON.parse(json); // Using json here, even though my request was async!
```

But it's not. Once you desugar it, all you get are promises, which are nonblocking:

```
fetch(…)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    const foo = JSON.parse(json);
  });
```

It would be absolutely catastrophic if `await` were blocking. JavaScript runtimes are *generally* single threaded. That means user interaction and other processes would cease whenever you made a request or some other async operation such as using the filesystem. On a related note, this is, along with dynamic imports, are the [main argument against top level `await`](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/0b6f317657f5167663b493c722647221)

Comment: Understood why the second call is not blocking the event loop. One quick question, when the promise resolves does the callback of `then` is pushed to call-stack by event loop, if not then how it got pushed to it?

Comment: @MohammadAziz Internally, `await` executes [PerformPromiseThen](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-performpromisethen) which is basically just `Promise#then`. In the operation, a [new Job is enqueued (with the callback)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-enqueuejob). And those jobs are executed once the call-stack is empty (so by the event loop, pushing new jobs to the call stack once it is empty).

Comment: Also, in the first example, you have the advantaje to manipulate the `response` and `json` objects. I mean, iterating the objects or getting another information.

Comment: If your `fakeDBCall` has no CPU work and still taking 5s, it'll block sockets. If there is CPU work that takes 5s, `await` is not going to help you to unblock event loop. It'll block event loop at a point.

Answer (score -1):

The async function returns a promise and you are passing in the request and response, I would change the 
    res.json(data) 
to 
    return res.json(data)

When an async function returns a value the promise is resolved, if the function contains an error the promise is rejected to just for cleanliness returning the res.json(data) will resolve the function.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question