# Using "map" with promises returns ordered and unordered results

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have this piece of code:

```
const Axios = require('axios');
const baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

async function main() {
    const posts = await Axios(`${baseURL}/posts`);
    const users = await Promise.all(posts.data.map( async (post, index) => {
        let d = await Axios(`${baseURL}/users/${post.userId}`);
        return d.data.name;
    }))

    users.map( (user, index) => {
        console.log( `${index}. ${user}` );
    });
}
```

And outputs the result in order:

```
1. Patricia
2. Glenna
3. Nicholas
4. Kurtis
5. Chelsey
```

Everything Ok, but ... If I do:

```
async function main() {
    const posts = await Axios(`${baseURL}/posts`);
    await Promise.all(posts.data.map( async (post, index) => {
        let d = await Axios(`${baseURL}/users/${post.userId}`);
        console.log( `${index}. ${d.data.name}` );
    }))
}
```

the `console.log` inside `map` prints the list unordered ...

```
2. Glenna
4. Kurtis
5. Chelsey
1. Patricia
3. Nicholas
```

**My question is:**

Why in the *first code* `map` returns the list *ordered*, and in the *second one* the `console.log` inside `map`, prints the list *unordered* ?

Comment: `.map()` does not pay attention to the promise that your async callback is returning so it doesn't wait for it to resolve.  Thus, all you're doing is launching a bunch of async operations at once and then seeing which ones finish first.

Comment: @jfriend00 So, the `await` does not stops the `.map()` iteration process while is waiting for the promise (Axios) result?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Your `.map()` does not wait for the `await` inside the callback.  So, the `console.log()` statements inside your second `.map()` are just a race between all the requests you've launched and they can finish in any order.  `Promise.all()` collects them all and puts them in proper order for you so when you look at the results of `await Promise.all()` you get them back in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Promise.all` is designed to keep the order of the results of the promises that were passed to it, independent of the order those promises actually resolved. So when `Promise.all` resolves, it means all individual promises resolved, and then `Promise.all` resolves to the array of resolutions *in the same order* as the corresponding promises have in the array.

If however you output the values *as soon as their promises resolve*, then the above has of course no effect on your output -- it will now be ordered by the order in which the individual promises resolve.

#### Simple example:

Let's say there are three promises `p1`,`p2`, `p3` that resolve to 1, 2 and 3. But the second promise will resolve sooner than the other two.

`Promise.all` is called with `[p1, p2, p3]`. It returns a new promise that will eventually resolve to `[1, 2, 3]`. During the time that not all promises are resolved, you could imagine that an internal array evolves as follows:

- `p2` resolves. `Promise.all` internally stores `[undefined, 2, undefined]`
- `p1` resolves. `Promise.all` internally stores `[1, 2, undefined]`
- `p3` resolves. `Promise.all` also resolves with value `[1, 2, 3]`

Here you can see that the first code would output 2, 1, 3 while the second would output 1, 2, 3

Comment: Who keeps the order in my first code: `Promise.all` or `.map()`?

Comment: Another Q: The `await Axios(${baseURL}/users/${post.userId})` stops the `.map()` iteration process while is waiting for the promise (Axios) result?

Comment: `map` also keeps order but is synchronous. In your first code it returns promises keeping order. `Promise.all` returns just one promise, but it will resolve asynchronously to an array that reflects the original order.

Comment: The inner `await Axios` does not stop the `map` process. `await` makes the callback to `map` return immediately with a new promise. All those created promises are returned by `map` immediately.

Comment: Amazing. I have always thought that `await` stopped the execution *where it is*, until returns the result of the promise.

Comment: Indeed, `await` is not blocking. The first one in an `async` function actually makes that function return a promise, and code execution continues after that function call. Only when the JS call stack is empty, and the `await`-ed promise resolves, will the function's context be *restored*, and then execution continues right after that `await`. See also explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44410481/5459839) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51583530/5459839).

Answer (score 1):

Because if you use asynchronus code it doesnt matter in which order you "fired" the requests, it only counts how long the response take.

So your result will be ordered in the way your requests finished, so if your request for x finished first, even if you fired it last, it will be still on the first position of your result

The map function is "blocking" which means that the second request is fired after the first is finished and so on.

here an example: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/

Comment: Yes, but why the results from the first code is returned in order?

Comment: The map function is "blocking" which means that the second request is fired after the first is finished and so on.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Promise.all(requests), all requests are made in parallel, therefore you can't know which ends before another.

In the first code you already had the result in the order of the array of requests. But in the second one, the console.log is in the order of responses.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Promise.all` executes promises in parallel and is async, while `.map` is blocking and executes with order and it won't finish until it iterates over all the items. It's like for-each loop.

If you want to achieve with ordering, either I suggest you to use `Bluebird.each` (library) or something like this:

```
const promiseEach = promises => {
  const results = [];

  return promises
    .reduce((acc, val, idx) => acc.then(_ => ((idx > 0 && results.push(_)), val)), Promise.resolve())
    .then(_ => [...results, _]);
}

const a1 = Promise.resolve(1);
const a2 = Promise.resolve(2);
const a3 = Promise.resolve(3);

const d1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 3000); }); // resolves after 3 seconds.
const d2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { setTimeout(() => resolve(2), 2000); }); // resolves after 2 seconds.
const d3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { setTimeout(() => resolve(3), 1000); }); // resolves after 1 seconds.

// this will respect orderings, before first promise is not resolved, does not goes to next one.
promiseEach([a1, a2, a3, d1, d2, d3]).then(console.log);
```

and pass your map to `promiseEach` function and they will be ordered.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your `reduce` in detail? I get lost on it

Comment: Oh.. hmm. What it does is, making promises to chain each other. For example, if you have N promises (a1, a2, ... aN) this reduce will produce something like: `Promise.resolve().then(() => a1).then(() => a2).then(...).then(() => aN)` (but also returns results returned from each chain) which means, unless first promise is not resolved, it won't continue to next chain and so on.

Comment: EDIT2: I suggest you to take a look at bluebird's each method (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html)

Comment: Ok. I'll take a look to ***Bluebird's each***. And about the `reduce`, I have made it in this way: `const promiseEach = async (promises) => 
    promises.reduce(async (acc, val) => {
        const collection = await acc;
        collection.push(await val);
        return collection
}, (async () => [])())` **Javascript is awesome !**

Comment: Ehm.. I would not suggest that ;d first of all, you have extra `async` which you don't really need (`async (promises) => ...`), second you can pass only array (not `async () => []`), so in the end it will become something like this: `const promiseEach = promises => promises.reduce(async (acc, val) => { acc.push(await val); return acc; }, []);`

Comment: EDIT: whatever you're doing there, you can just write with for-loop, it's the same then. `const result = []; for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) { result.push(await promises[i]); } return result;` but it's not a good practice to write async code in loops though, what I wrote there is different.

Comment: By saying "not a good practice", I mean they're executed immediately (just like `Promise.all` does) instead of waiting for previous one to finish.